# How to check elements availability in sql database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there any shorter way for the following problem statement?

I've 1000 of items list
e.g`let items=[{"code":"816","name":"item-a"}, {"code":"230","name":"item-b"},{"code":"00040","name":"item-c"},{"code":"89586","name":"item-d"}, .... up to 1000 objects]`

Data is available in mysql database.

How to check from the items array which products are available in sql db & which are not?

If I'll use $in operator, then I'll get whatever data present in db but I want 2 separate arrays one for available items in db & another one for unavailable items in db.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more-efficient approach to doing this. But the first solution that comes to my mind is something like

```
const dbResults = await Product.findAll()
const dbCodes = dbResults.map(product => product.get().code)
const includedProducts = []
const nonincludedProducts = []
items.forEach(item => {
    if (dbCodes.includes(item.code) includedProducts.push(item)
    else nonincludedProducts.push(item)
}
```

Let the server code handle the filtering rather than making thousands of calls to the database or using a very expensive IN operator.